# set css stylinng for all elements based on the lang attribute

Tags: html, css

I have set lang attribute in the "body" tag. I have different set of languages in my application. I need to set separate styling for all elements based on the different lang values.

e.g:

- if lang=es-cl, need to set different set of styling.
- if lang=pt-br, set different set of styling.

What is the best practice for achieving this (in using css only) ?.


Can I do something like the following (parent child something like that). 
body:lang(it) {
   
   
  .header {
    ...css styling..
  }
  
  .content .left-panel {
    ...css styling...
  }

}

Thanks

Comment: Can't believe I don't find a dupe... But what you want is `:lang` pseudo class. There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682006/css-lang-pseudo-class-vs-attribute-selector) but they already did the little research you are missing here...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS value Selector , 
[attribute*="value"] :

```
[lang="es-cl"]
```

or

```
[lang="pt-br"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this using CSS attribute selector

```
div[lang="en"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

and CSS pseudo-class

```
div:lang(en) {
  css declarations;
}
```

This select all div element with `lang="en"` attribute. If you want to select all element with attribute `lang="en"` remove div from the CSS selector.

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to set lang attribute to every element ? ( I have already set in the body tag). Bit confused how to set the css for different languages (i'm pretty new to css).

Comment: @ChamalPerera No, you don't have to set lang attribute to every element. Apply this to `body` element or parent element containing every element you want to style, example: `body:lang(en) {css here}`, it will apply the CSS to all child element of body.